# Formula for Leemis's m

Tags: statistical-significance, small-sample, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm looking for the formula to calculate the statistics and the significance level of Leemis's m. [Wikipedia reports the statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law#Statistical_tests) as
$$m = \sqrt{N}\cdot\max_{i=1}^9 \left\{ \left|\Pr (X \text{ has FSD}=i)-\log_{10}
\left( 1 + \frac 1 i \right) \right| \right\}\,$$
but I need to calculate the significance associated with each value. I'm using it to calculate Benford's law probabilities. It seems similar to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but there are corrections applied to it to make it more robust for small samples.

Leemis et al. (2000) discuss it in the paper [*Survival Distributions Satisfying Benford's Law*](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/viewer.html?pdfurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.wm.edu%2F%7Eleemis%2F2000amstat.pdf&clen=191224&chunk=true), but refer to his textbook (1995) *Reliability: Probabilistic Models and Statistical
Methods*, which I do not possess, for the tables containing the values and significance levels.

Comment: You could simply simulate to obtain critical values for some desired significance level -- but keep in mind the distribution of this test statistic is discrete, so the available significance levels will be also. It may be important to pay attention to what available significance levels are particularly if sample sizes are small.